# jquery text area length count?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text area field where i need to provide information about the word count when the user enters some text in the field. Length of the field is supposed to be 500 Characters.
Initialy it must show

> min characters:100 | 0 of 500 // 0 of 500 must be in red color

and once the user enters come character need to update the count as well. Once the user reaches the count say the min character 100, i need to display

> min characters:100 | 100 of 500 // 100 of 500 must be in green color.

How can i do this?? is there any plugin for the same???
let me know your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try to use this plugin feature**

[jquery-character-counter from jqeasy.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20150317063551/http://www.jqeasy.com/jquery-character-counter)

Comment: thanks mohan, I have modified the js file to include my requirement and is working fine.

Comment: sweet plug-in. very easy to use saved me at least 30 minutes of coding. +1

Comment: Just found this answer, great stuff, +1

Comment: jqeasy.com seems to have gone... anyone know where this content is now?

Comment: @RichardMorgan see my response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506959/jquery-text-area-length-count/8185414#8185414

Answer (score 66):

Simplest way to count:

```
var count = $("#your_textarea").val().length;
```

Comment: Maybe you also want to trim white spaces at the beginning and end of your value: `var count = $("#your_textarea").val().trim().length;`

Answer (score 25):

```
$("#your-text-area").on('keyup', function(event) {
    var currentString = $("#your-text-area").val()
    $("Your Div").html(currentString.length);
    if (currentString.length <= 500 )  {  /*or whatever your number is*/
       //do some css with your div
    } else {
       //do some different stuff with your div
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: this is updating the count on change. I want that when i type something.

Comment: @nimi so you should checkout the (ON)KEYUP event ;)

Answer (score 2):

i use

jQuery Textarea Characters Counter Plugin

Examples and documentation at: http://roy-jin.appspot.com/jsp/textareaCounter.jsp

Comment: I'm looking for something similar. I saw that plugin earlier... I don't think it provides minimum character count, though.

Answer (score 2):

I was having trouble with the onkeydown event and had success with onkeyup. Here's the code I came up with to count down the remaining characters (with a limit of 120)

```
$(function() {
  var input = $('#my-input'), display = $('.char-count'), count = 0, limit = 120;

  count = input.val().length
  remaining = limit - count
  update(remaining);

  input.keyup(function(e) {
    count = $(this).val().length;
    remaining = limit - count;

    update(remaining);
  });

  function update(count) {
    var txt = ( Math.abs(count) === 1 ) ? count + ' Character Remaining' :  count + ' Characters Remaining'
    display.html(txt);
  }

});
```