# validate length of textarea

Tags: jquery

hi i am working on SMS panel and i want to check to length of text area now i am using these code :

```
        $("#txt").keydown(function () {
            var len = $(this).val().length;
            $("#lbl").text(len);
            if (len <= 70) {
                $("#lbl").text("One SMS");
                if (confirm("more than one sms are you sure?")) {
                    $("#lbl").text(len);
                }
            }
            else if (len >= 71 && len <= 133) {
                $("#lbl").text("two SMS");
                if (confirm("more than two sms are you sure?")) {
                    $("#lbl").text(len);
                }
            }
            else if (len > 134 && len <= 199) {
                $("#lbl").text("three SMS");
                alert("more than three sms are you sure?");
            }
        });
```

i want when i paste text into textArea alert is displayed and select no cant input anything

thanks in your advise?

Comment: The first advice - to ask answerable questions. "not perfectly" is not an explanation at all.

Comment: have look at this
[textarea lenght count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506959/jquery-text-area-length-count)

Comment: @zerkms for example when i copy text into textarea it's not working.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar i dont want to use plug-ing

Comment: i disagree you code should not work with this conditions ....

Comment: @PranayRana it's working when 'len' reach these amount character.

Comment: @sirwan:have you seen other answers posted below.

Comment: its good you updated your code finally...now people can try to resolve your actual problem...

Comment: @Sirwan Afifi: "for example when i copy text into textarea it's not working" -- as I said - "not working" isn't an explanation. Do you see just a black screen with nothing on it? Is it so difficult to **EXPLAIN** what you see and what you expect to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean:

```
else if (len >= 71 && len <= 133) {
     $("#lbl").text("two SMS");
     if (confirm("more than two sms are you sure?")) {
         $("#lbl").text(len);
     }
}
else if (len >= 134 && len <= 199) {
       $("#lbl").text("three SMS");
       alert("more than three sms are you sure?");
}
```

Comment: It's not a problem. When you reach certain amount of characters - the alert appears.

Comment: no,i have to check length of one sms for example first SMS is with lenght 70 ,second one is 63 and and another one 66

Answer (score 0):

> but it's not working perfectly,

One of the error I could see that is not making it work perfectly is, you have used the keydown event to work on  finding the length, so if you copy and paste there is no Keydown event happening so you cannot find the length there, so you can write the same function in the onchange event of the text box,  so that when you copy and paste your data also you can find the length

```
  $("input").change(function(){
    //your function of finding the length goes here
  });
```

If you post the exact problem it will be easier to get help.

Hope this helps :D